# Install Enterprise iPhone App for 5000+ devices

Tags: ios, ios4

Before the Enterprise App can be installed in employee's device, is the Provisioning Profile necessary to include all UDID of the 5000+ devices? If yes, how to input the UDID in Apple Provisioning Portal in batch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, may I recommend the following document and URL:

```
http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/resources/
```

To answer your questions directly:

- You can batch upload UDIDs, yes - but there is still a limit of 100 devices per year. To batch upload, log into the iOS Developer Portal at `developer.apple.com` and click on Devices on the left-hand column and then look for the row Bulk Upload of Devices for detailed instructions.
- If your aim is to build and deploy an Enterprise iOS app - assuming you have registered for the Enterprise developers program (currently $299 per year) at `http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/` - you can create a distribution provisioning profile and build an archive of your app. (as .ipa format) With these two files, you can host them on your Intranet (for example) and any iOS device can then download and install the app.

There is one final part with my 2nd point above; if you go to the link below and follow their instructions, it'll generate a small HTML and .plist file ... if you open these in a text editor, you will soon see how to tweak them so that you can hook up your previously-created .ipa and .mobileprovision file. If any iOS device then visits that HTML file, it'll be able to download and install your app with great ease.

```
http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/
```

Comment: If the Provisioning Profile + IPA leaked to public, that means all devices in the world can install the Enterprise app?

Comment: Correct - Apple strongly recommend that as a developer, your client should be the party responsible for purchasing and registering an Enterprise developers account, and then they should grant you access to develop with it. Regardless, there have not yet been any documented cases of Apple revoking an Enterprise developers account where a developer owns it and has deployed multiple apps for different clients. Hope this helps!